# React native deep link breaks UI in Android

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

So I tried deep linking in react native, it is for user login using web view.
The flow is like this:

1. user clicks on login button.
2. browser shows up, and users do their login activity.
3. after user login I redirect user back to my app using deep linking

the problem is after my app reopen, the status bar is not translucent anymore

here is image before deep link:
[image: before deep linking]

here is image after deep link:
[image: after deep linking]

here is the code to make statusbar translucent:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <RootNavigation />
  {Platform.OS === 'android' &&
    <StatusBar
      translucent
      backgroundColor={Token.color.background.statusbar.rgb} />}
  {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle='default' />}
</View>
```

here is dependencies that I use, maybe it can help:

```
"axios": "^0.17.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.49.3",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.3",
"react-native-svg": "^5.4.2",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this is a different entry point for the Android App. You need to make sure that your *status bar translucent* component is included in this entry point. 
To replicate this behavior and test open project in Android Studio and Click on Run -> Edit Configuration. and the change Launch options to URL and update URL to something like this -  myapp://article/13 . This will help to debug you ithe n simulator of Android.

Check out more details here in Testing Deeplink on Android section -> https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/react-native-deep-linking-for-ios-and-android-d33abfba7ef3